# Cannot save today's date in mySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, date

This is a simple solution, but I cannot get it to work even after reading many similar posts on the topic.

I am able to define a php variable to hold the current date because I can echo it properly:

```
$_date_today = date('Y-d-m');
echo $_date_today;

2017-31-03
```

But when I try to use that php variable to insert the date value into mySQL table, the value inserted is 0000-00-00. My date_order column in the table is defined as DATE.

Comment: Mysql's format is Y-m-d, not Y-d-m

Comment: and if `id` is an AI... then your query failed for it also; on 2 counts.

Comment: Thank you aynber and others. The Y-d-m format was an easy fix. Not sure how I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While mySQL always stores the date in the database using the same format and I don't believe it can be changed, you can format the date however you want when retrieving it using the many mySQL functions available... see the following link: [mySQL date manimpulation functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

try to change the date format cause mysql format is `Y-m-d` and you are entering `Y-d-m`

try use this `$_date_today = date('Y-m-d');` insted of `$_date_today = date('Y-d-m');`